# What is the correct Japanese translation for "pull down to refresh" in an app context?

Tags: word-choice, translation

I am currently studying Japanese, and one of my approaches for studying is by translating applications (since I also make apps for a living).

How do I correctly translate "pull down to refresh"?
Which of the following is the most correct one?

1. リフレッシュするために引き下げてください
2. リフレッシュするために下へ引いてください
3. リフレッシュするためにプルダウンしてください

Or do you have a better translation?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I decided to use @Szymon 's answer because it has the highest votest as of 2014/05/07. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Facebook app (for Android) has it as:

> 下{した}へスライドして更新{こうしん}...

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Gmail app for Android:

> 下にスワイプして更新

[image]

Answer (score 2):

引っ【ひっ】張って【ぱって】離す【はなす】と更新【こうしん】(します。)

Comment: While technically accurate, this has a distinctly translated-from-English feel for me